# How to do it some items or headers should not render multiple time in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have Table on right side there is columns on the top each box there is heading so . I just Want that. that heading should not repeat. on each box . it should only repeat on the top of the column.

here is code - https://snack.expo.dev/@xeteke8423/sellerformat

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by passing the `index` prop to the `SecondaryBox` and render the heading conditionally.

Make following changes in your codebase:

App.js:

```js
//.......
              <View>
                {sample.map((item) => (
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    {item['sellerId']?.map((buyer, index) => (
                      <SecondaryBox sellerId={buyer} index={index} />
                    ))}
                  </View>
                ))}
              </View>
//.......
```

And in your `SecondaryBox.js` render the heading conditionally like below:

```js
//............
<ScrollView horizontal>
          {
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <View style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
                {index === 0 ? (
                  <View style={{position: ""}}>
                    <Text>Seller Profile</Text>
                    <Text>View Remark</Text>
                    <Text>Unit/Price</Text>
                  </View>
                ) : (
                  <View style={{ height: 55 }}></View>
                )}
//............
```

Here is the output:

[image]